# FCM Server Side implementation in nodejs

Tags: android, node.js

I am using fcm-node module to send the message for android device.
I got the success response "**Successfully sent with response:  {"multicast_id":8475336616034933807,"success":
1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1476702887389532%995
cf878995cf878"}]}** ".

But I couldn't see the message in console and i didn't receive any message to the device.But when i try to send the notification through console it is working fine.

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
            Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

            // Check if message contains a data payload.
            if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
            }

            // Check if message contains a notification payload.
            if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            }

        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
    }
```

Comment: Provide onMessageReceived code, you can find this in FirebaseMessagingService class

Comment: public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        }
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }
sendNotification method below.
    }. This the code.

Comment: update this in question

Answer (score 0):

inseted of

```
remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody()
```

try this

```
remoteMessage.getData().get("message")
```